# Executar uma lista de executáveis

Tags: c

Estou tentando implementar um programa que execute concorrentemente uma lista de executáveis especificados como argumentos da linha de comando , considerando os executáveis sem quaisquer argumentos próprios. O programa deverá esperar pelo fim da execução de todos processos por si criados.

Só poderei usar estas funções para executar :

```
int execl(const char*path, const char*arg0, ..., NULL);
int execlp(const char*file, const char*arg0, ..., NULL);
int execv(const char*path, char*const argv[]);
int execvp(const char*file, char*const argv[]);
```

Isto foi o que criei até agora :

```
void main (int args , char **s) {

   int  i , x , status;

   if (args >= 2) {

    x = fork ();

    for ( i = 1 ; i < args ; i++) {

         if (x == 0) {
            execvp (s[i],&s[i]);
            x = fork();
         }
         else
         {
            wait (&status);
            _exit(i);
         }
      }
  }
   _exit(0);
}
```

Mas o programa só executa o primeiro argumento da `main`.
Como posso alterar o código para que faça o que quero?

Comment: acho que a melhor forma de fazer um sistema com concorrência, é usar `threads` ao invés de `fork`, o `fork` cria um novo processo, e as variáveis só podem ser usadas em um processo(exceto se for uma variável compartilhada)

Comment: Foi o que pensei @BrumazziD.B. , no entanto só posso usar o fork e os execs respetivos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
         if (x == 0) {
            execvp (s[i],&s[i]);
            x = fork();          // <== nunca executa
         }
```

Este segundo `fork()` nunca executa.
Depois do `execvp()` o programa actual é substituido por outro e o `fork()` deixa de "existir".

---

Primeiro fazes o `fork()`. Depois, apenas no filho, fazes o `exec()`. Assim ficas com dois processos activos: o pai a correr o programa original e o filho a correr o programa do exec.

```
// basicamente (MUITO BASICAMENTE) é isto
if (fork() == 0) {
    exec();     // o filho passa a executar outro programa
}               // o pai continua a executar este programa
```

Há um [artigo na Wikipedia (em inglês) sobre o *fork-exec*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fork%E2%80%93exec).

Comment: Muito bem observado @pmg . Portanto se usar qualquer exec ele nao faz o processo do fork? Como faço para que o exec seja executado de acordo com o fork?